# Intersect of two sorted arrays

Tags: c++, algorithm

**Question> Given two sorted array A and B, return an array C containing elements common to A and B. The array C cannot contain duplicates.**

Here is my solution, but my hunch is that it is wrong. But I cannot find a counter-example to dis-approve it.
Can someone point it out for me? Or give me a counter-example?

Update:

The algorithm works as follows:

We hold one pointer to each array and move these pointers forward until we find a common element. Then if the common element is NOT in C, the found element is stored in C. Otherwise, depend on the element, we move the pointer forward accordingly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

vector<int> Intersect(const vector<int>& vecIntsA, const vector<int>& vecIntB)
{
    int indA = 0;
    int indB = 0;
    vector<int> vecIntC;

    while(indA < vecIntsA.size() && indB < vecIntB.size())
    {
        if (vecIntsA[indA] == vecIntB[indB]) {
            if ( vecIntC.empty() || vecIntC.back() != vecIntsA[indA])
                vecIntC.emplace_back(vecIntsA[indA]);
            indA++;
            indB++;
        } else if (vecIntsA[indA] < vecIntB[indB]) 
            indA++;
        else // (vecIntsA[indA] > vecIntB[indB]) 
            indB++;        
    }

    return vecIntC;
}

int main()
{
   default_random_engine dre;
   uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, 100);

   vector<int> vecIntA;
   for(int i=0; i < 20; ++i)
    vecIntA.emplace_back(dist(dre));   
   sort(vecIntA.begin(), vecIntA.end());
   copy(vecIntA.cbegin(), vecIntA.cend(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, ","));
   cout << endl;

   vector<int> vecIntB;
   for(int i=0; i < 24; ++i)
    vecIntB.emplace_back(dist(dre));   
   sort(vecIntB.begin(), vecIntB.end());
   copy(vecIntB.cbegin(), vecIntB.cend(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, ","));
   cout << endl;

   vector<int> vecIntC = Intersect(vecIntA, vecIntB);
   copy(vecIntC.cbegin(), vecIntC.cend(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, ","));

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I feel like this is one of those questions where everyone is going to have much better input if we knew what your algorithm was in plain English first. Besides, that also helps separate out problems with the *algorithm*, and problems with the *implementation*.

Comment: Consider the case when the inputs contain repeated elements.

Comment: @Mark, please see the output result for your case.A: 0,0,1,2,2,4,5,5,6,6,6,7,8,9,11,13,13,14,15,15,18,18,20,21,24,
B: 0,2,2,3,3,4,6,6,6,8,8,10,10,10,11,11,14,16,17,
C: 0,2,4,6,8,11,14,

Comment: Sorry, I see that you have special tests to cover that case. My bad. I can't find anything else wrong with this code.

Comment: Yes, I start to think my code is correct. But I am waiting for more reviewers. Specifically, I am not sure `( vecIntC.empty() || vecIntC.back() != vecIntsA[indA])` is correct in all cases.

Comment: @q0987 You can also try asking on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Xiaofu, you are right. But first I though my code is wrong and it is better to post here.

Comment: "What's wrong with my code" questions are typically off topic for [so]. ["Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Might fit on [codereview.se] - ["Correctness in unanticipated cases"](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

You could always use the STL algorithms set_intersection and unique?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick solution with time complexity (p+q), where p and q are lengths of array A and B, respectively.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

set<int> intersect(vector<int> &A, vector<int> &B) {
    int j = 0;
    vector<int> V;
    for(int i = 0;i<A.size();i++){
        first:
        if(j == B.size()) break;
        if(A[i] == B[j]){
            V.push_back(A[i]);
            j++;
        }
        else if(A[i]>B[j]) { j++;goto first;}
    }
    set<int> S(V.begin(), V.end());
    return S;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> A,B;
    A = {1,2,3,3,4,5,6};
    B = {3,3,5,6};
    set<int> S;
    S = intersect(A,B);     
    set<int>::iterator iter;
    for(iter=S.begin(); iter!=S.end();++iter){
        cout<<(*iter)<<" ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is a `2-pointer` solution. Try to look for monotonicity in one of the loops as other loops move forward. If you find that, you have found your optimization. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm seems reasonable.  For what it's worth, I recently solved the exact same problem and came up with [a similar algorithm](https://github.com/tmoertel/practice/blob/master/EPI/13/soln_13_005_intersect_sorted_arrays.py#L196) for the case when the two arrays are of similar length.

In general, if you want to support the belief your algorithms produce good solutions, express the fundamental properties of good solutions in a way that you can check automatically.  Then write automated tests against those properties.  (This is a great style of testing popularized by [QuickCheck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickCheck).)

For this problem, for example, I expressed the fundamental property of array intersection as follows:  "Given an intersection function `f`, for all sorted arrays `A` and `B`, `f(A, B) == sorted(set(A) & set(B))`."  (In Python, `set(xs)` produces a set from the elements of `xs`, and the `&` operator applied to sets computes intersections.)  In essence, I mapped the desired semantics of array intersection into Python's built-in semantics for sorting and set intersection. That way, I could build a correctness oracle for my implementation out of cheap, readily available parts.  The final step was constructing random test cases and checking whether the mapping held (by consulting the oracle) for all of them.

Here's the corresponding code:

```
def check_function(f):
# fundamental property:
# forall sorted arrays A, B. intersect(A, B) == sorted(set(A) & set(B))
from math import factorial
from random import randrange
from nose.tools import assert_equal
for N in xrange(8):
    for _ in xrange(factorial(N)):  # get decent sample of problem space
        m, n = randrange(N + 1), randrange(N + 1)
        A = sorted(randrange(N + 1) for _ in xrange(m))
        B = sorted(randrange(N + 1) for _ in xrange(n))
        got = f(A, B)
        expected = sorted(set(A) & set(B))
        assert_equal(got, expected)
```